# ADO Connection Timeout

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am seeing a timeout error for some users w/large transactions. I am not clear the implications of:

1. Using cnn.ConnectionTimeout vs cnn.CommandTimeout?
2. Setting a very long timeout period (how long is too long?)
3. Setting timeout = 0 (indeterminate?)

Here is a snippet:

```
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'cnn.ConnectionTimeout = 30    
'cnn.CommandTimeout = 30

cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server}; server=" & myIP & ";Trusted_Connection=no;Database=" & myDatabase & ";UID= " & myUser & ";PWD= " & myPass & "
cnn.Open

strSQL = "uspDeleteAreaCommon @InvID = '" & myInvID & "';"
Set rs = cnn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Any suggestions/cautions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No replies.

I used cnn.CommandTimeout = 0  (infinite timeout?)

With no complaint, though I am still not clear the implications of this setting...